# NSDate and NSDate stringFromDate are inconsistent

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I am trying to convert a mysql datetime field to another timezone. The conversion seems correct when I print the date object, however when I print the date as a string the time is incorrect. Source code and output are below.

### Source:

*edited - print original interval in seconds and string, add timezones*

```
interval = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: seconds];
NSLog(@"interval in ms: %@",interval); 
self.dateStamp = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds/1000];


if(![currentZone.name isEqualToString: timezone]){          //need to convert
    NSDateFormatter *fromTZ = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [fromTZ setTimeZone:currentZone];
    [fromTZ setDateFormat:@"hh:mm yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSLog(@"original date: %@",[fromTZ stringFromDate:self.dateStamp]);
    NSDateFormatter *toTZ = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [toTZ setTimeZone:spotZone];
    [toTZ setDateFormat:@"hh:mm yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString *tempdate = [fromTZ stringFromDate:self.dateStamp];
    NSDate *toDate = [toTZ dateFromString:tempdate];
    NSLog(@"Date: %@",toDate);
    NSLog(@"Date String: %@", [toTZ stringFromDate:toDate]);
}
```

### Output:

> > interval in ms: 1384193573000
> >
> > original date: 01:12 2013-11-11 //date in current timezone: America/Phoenix
> >
> > Date: 2013-11-11 08:12:00 +0000 //date in new timezone: America/New York
> >
> > Date String: 01:12 2013-11-11

Comment: They are the same. It's just that when you log an `NSDate` it is shown in UTC time.

Comment: You are in a -7 timezone.

Comment: I need to print this date as a string to the UI, can you help me understand how I would do that? @rmaddy

Comment: You're already doing it with `[toTZ stringFromDate:toDate];`.

Comment: The date is showing as 1:12AM (second output) instead of 8:12PM (first output) which is the correct time. @rmaddy

Comment: Use the correct timezone on the formatter.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the time is off by 5 hours..

Comment: Note that 1) the date format for hours is `HH`, not `hh`. 2) `NSLog(@"Date: %@",toDate)` prints the date with respect to UTC. - If that does not help, please provide complete information: The input `self.dateStamp`, the used time zones, the intermediate result `tempdate` and the final result `toDate`.

Comment: @MartinR changing to HH does not affect the output other than changing it to 24 hour format. I added the data you requested, the output for the interval in ms and the original date. At this point I'm just confused and need to figure out how to get my desired result. In my db I am storing the time as 18:12 and a separate field for timezone which is "America/Phoenix" i want this time to display as 20:12 America/New York time or 8:12PM. Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server sends the time `1384193573000` (in milliseconds) since 1.1.1970, but not with respect to GMT as it is usually done, but with respect to a different time zone, "America/Phoenix" in your example.

Therefore you have to add a correction first, which is the difference between "America/Phoenix" and GMT:

```
NSTimeInterval serverTime = 1384193573000/1000.;
NSTimeZone *fromZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Phoenix"];
NSTimeInterval diff = [fromZone secondsFromGMTForDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0]];
NSDate *dateStamp = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(serverTime - diff)];
```

This was the crucial step. `dateStamp` is now a "proper" `NSDate` object representing
the time sent from the server.
What remains is to *display* the date. That is done as in the above comments and the other
answer. For example:

```
NSTimeZone *toZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"];
NSDateFormatter *toTZ = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[toTZ setTimeZone:toZone];
[toTZ setDateFormat:@"HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *result = [toTZ stringFromDate:dateStamp];

// result = 20:12 2013-11-11
```

Answer (score 2):

`NSDate` has no concept of time zone, it is simply an object representing the number of seconds since January 1, 2001 GMT and represented in UTC. No matter what you try and set it to, when you straight log an `NSDate` its going to give you the same result. The only way to circumvent this is to use the `NSDateFormatter` which you've already done. Everything you've posted is the expected behavior.